# Play Framework: migrating configuration from 2.3.8 to 2.4.1

Tags: playframework

The migration guide for Play 2.4.1 says `evolutionplugin = disabled` can be safely omitted if one is not using evolution... but what's about `dbplugin = disabled` and `ehcacheplugin = disabled`? Does the same principle apply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're old, they used to be present as follows:

`play.api.cache.EhCachePlugin#enabled`:

```
  /**
   * Is this plugin enabled.
   *
   * {{{
   * ehcacheplugin.disabled=true
   * }}}
   */
  override lazy val enabled = {
    !app.configuration.getString("ehcacheplugin").filter(_ == "disabled").isDefined
  }
```

`play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin#isDisabled`:

```
  /**
   * plugin is disabled if either configuration is missing or the plugin is explicitly disabled
   */
  private lazy val isDisabled = {
    app.configuration.getString("dbplugin").filter(_ == "disabled").isDefined || dbConfig.subKeys.isEmpty
  }
```

both of which have now gone.  Regarding the cache, 2.4 [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaCache) says:

> It is possible to provide a custom implementation of the CacheApi that either replaces, or sits along side the default implementation.
>
> To replace the default implementation, you’ll need to disable the default implementation by setting the following in application.conf:
>
> play.modules.disabled += "play.api.cache.EhCacheModule"

Regarding the database, simply not including the `jdbc` and any other database library dependencies will suffice.